# cant generate thumbnail using ffmpg of php

Tags: php, ffmpeg, phpvibe

i host my phpvibe website on 247host, When i upload everything works fine except two things. When i am uploading videos then thumbnail is not generating and total time of video is not generating. When i contact their customer support they send me screen shot of terminal in which root executing my command and thumbnail is generated. but when i am doing this in vibecron.php then its not working. I purchased shared hosting, I dont have access to apache log, Now i am not able to understand why my script not working on server? and how i can test.

Here is my vibecron.php

```
 <?php error_reporting(E_ALL); 
        //Vital file include
        require_once("load.php");
        $tp = ABSPATH.'/'.get_option('tmp-folder','rawmedia')."/";
        $fp = ABSPATH.'/'.get_option('mediafolder')."/";
        $ip = ABSPATH.'/'.get_option('mediafolder').'/thumbs/'; ;
        //Run conversions
        $crons = $db->get_results("select id,tmp_source,token from ".DB_PREFIX."videos where tmp_source != '' and source = '' limit 0,100000");
        if($crons) {
        foreach ($crons as $cron) {
        $db->query("UPDATE  ".DB_PREFIX."videos SET tmp_source='' WHERE id = '".intval($cron->id)."'");
        $output ="{ffmpeg-cmd} -i {input} -vcodec libx264 -s {ffmpeg-vsize} -threads 4 -movflags faststart {output}.mp4";
        //$output ="{ffmpeg-cmd} -i {input} -vcodec libx264 -s {ffmpeg-vsize} -threads 4 -strict experimental {output}.mp4";
        $input = $tp.$cron->tmp_source;
        $final = $fp.$cron->token;
        $check = $fp.$cron->token.'.mp4';
        $source= 'localfile/'.$cron->token.'.mp4';
        if (file_exists($input)) {  
        //Start video conversion
        $out = str_replace(array('{ffmpeg-cmd}','{input}','{ffmpeg-vsize}','{ffmpeg-bitrate}','{output}'),array(get_option('ffmpeg-cmd','ffmpeg'), $input, get_option('ffmpeg-vsize','640x360'), get_option('ffmpeg-bitrate','1750'),$final), $output);
        shell_exec($out);

        //Extract thumbnail
        $imgout = "{ffmpeg-cmd} -itsoffset -4 -i {input} -y -f image2  -ss ".get_option('ffmpeg-thumb-time','00:00:03')." -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s 500x300 {output}";
        $imgfinal = $ip.$cron->token.'.jpg';
        $thumb = str_replace(ABSPATH.'/' ,'',$ip.$cron->token.'.jpg');
        $imgout = str_replace(array('{ffmpeg-cmd}','{input}','{output}'),array(get_option('ffmpeg-cmd','ffmpeg'), $input,$imgfinal), $imgout);
        exec ( $imgout);
        // Update so far
        $db->query("UPDATE  ".DB_PREFIX."videos SET thumb='".$thumb."', source='".$source."', pub = '".intval(get_option('videos-initial'))."'  WHERE id = '".intval($cron->id)."'");
        //Extract Duration

        $cmd = get_option('ffmpeg-cmd','ffmpeg')." -i ".$check;
        exec ( "$cmd 2>&1", $output );
        $text = implode ( "\r", $output );
        if (preg_match ( '!Duration: ([0-9:.]*)[, ]!', $text, $matches )) {
                    list ( $v_hours, $v_minutes, $v_seconds ) = explode ( ":", $matches [1] );
                    // duration in time format
                    $d = $v_hours * 3600 + $v_minutes * 60 + $v_seconds;            
                }
        if(isset($d)) {     
        list ( $duration, $trash ) = explode ( ".", $d );
        }       



        if(isset($duration)) {
        $db->query("UPDATE  ".DB_PREFIX."videos SET duration='".$duration."' WHERE id = '".intval($cron->id)."'");
        }
         add_activity('4', $cron->id); 
        /* End this loops item */
        }
        }
        $db->clean_cache();
        } 

        ?>
```

Comment: Have you tested your code in the local server?

Answer (score 0):

They have a tester under "Requirements", and that's the first thing you should read when buying a script.

Make sure your ffmpeg works and your paths to ffmpeg in the cms and also that the ffmpeg version on server is right, they support 1.0+.

That php you've posted works fine for them, it's the config in the admin or the ffmpeg on your server the issue.